# I have Textbox in ASP.Net, to which cursor should not be entered by the user but just to display. I cant use enable property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Textbox in ASP.Net, to which cursor should not be entered.

Comment: post the code you have so we can try to triage it

Comment: A question with a longer title than the body, something new every day

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox"  runat="server"  ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>..This is my code..

Comment: @AnilMadhavarapu: 1. use your favorite search machine to find the duplicate questions 2. show your effort and tell us why it doesn't work 3. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or even [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: ReadOnly='true' should do what you asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of css like this:
Put a cssClass name:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="textBox1" runat="server" />
```

and within style tags:

```css
<style>
    .textBox1 {
     cursor:not-allowed;
    }
</style>
```

It will not allow the cursor to enter within textBox as you asked.